# Resolve dependency from singleton property

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Let us assume I have an interface

```
public interface IMyInterface { }
```

And a class that exposes this interface as a property:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public IMyInterface Property { get; set; }
}
```

`MyClass` is registered as a Singleton with my Windsor container.  I would like to wire up the windsor container so that `IMyInterface` resolves to the property "Property" on the instance of `MyClass`, which I can achieve as follows:

```
container.Register(Component.For<MyClass>().ImplementedBy<MyClass>().LifeStyle.Singleton);
var myClass = container.Resolve<MyClass>();
container.Register(Component.For<IMyInterface>().Instance(myClass.Property));
```

However, I would prefer to have the container do all my resolving for me so I don't have to make the call to `container.Resolve` above.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Is the `MyClass` filling that property itself?

Comment: Yes - `MyClass` is responsible for providing the implementation of `IMyInterface`.

Comment: Why does this class do this? This seems to be the root of your configuration issues. In general it should be the composition root that is responsible for this.

Comment: `MyClass` is an API for a third party.  One way to solve my issue is to make `IInterface` a constructor dependency of `MyClass`.  However, in the interests of keeping the number of "moving parts" at a minumum to make the API more palatable I am happy to sacrifice a "purer" dependency injection philosophy in favour of fewer registrations.

Answer (score 2):

If the `MyClass` is responsible of creating that instance, you can't magically remove the registration for `IMyInterface`. You need to register something, but your configuration can be made a bit simpler by using a factory delegate as follows:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IMyInterface>() 
    .UsingFactoryMethod(() => container.Resolve<MyClass>().Property) 
    .LifeStyle.Transient);
```

Comment: Thank you - although it didn't answer my question (which may not even be possible) that is certainly an improvement on what I had before.

Answer (score 0):

If you register the `IMyInterface` as a singleton, there will be only one instance of the component; any resolution will return the same instance. Whether it comes from the property or not does not change the resolution

In fact this behavior by the container makes me question why it is important that you resolve through a particular accessor? Is there some additional processes in the getter to the property you've not mentioned?

---

Regarding the fact you don't want to resolve the `MyClass` to access its property, You *have* to retrieve an instance of the class if you don't make the property static, you won't be able to sidestep this.

Answer (score 0):

Is this IMyInterface the interface from the third party library which you implement in order to use it? If this is so than I can conclude IMyInterface is 100% needed for your implementation to work.

An important note to keep in mind - Any software developer who encounters your class will not know that IMyInterface is real dependency of this class because it is a property - anybody can reset it somewhere. When you put your dependencies in ctor your are guaranteed that everybody will notice that this is a hard dependency without which the class is not supposed to work. In general - "hard" dependencies come through ctor, others may be exposed as properties.

> However, in the interests of keeping the number of "moving parts" at a minumum to make the API more palatable I am happy to sacrifice a "purer" dependency injection philosophy in favour of fewer registrations.

Keep in mind that the DI principles come from practice and maintainability and readability must outweigh palatability. If somebody else maintains your code it will be easier to spot the dependency in ctor rather than as a property. Therefore palatability is an illusion because you know what your code is doing (now).

My advice is to stay with constructor injection of IMyInterface and just make a typed factory and get it through the constructor.